# Is it possible to use DV360 API for youtube campaigns?

Tags: google-api, dv360

I am trying to modify line items through DV360 API. I am able to do it for Display campaigns but while using the same code for Youtube campaigns its returning 404 content not found even when LI exists with the same LI ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible through SDF v5.2 and above. You can download SDF programatically and modify line items in csv file and upload it back to DV360.
But there is only catch is you cannot upload it programatically you have to upload it through dashboard only. You can do anything create, update and all.

URL for Format reference: https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/structured-data-file/v5-3/LineItem

URL for downloading SDF: https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/guides/downloading-sdfs/download#python

Enjoy!!